# Implementing source term in heat equation

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

Looking at a stationary heat equation with a source term:
$0,024*U_{xx}+120.700.000=0$.

The source term is the combustion heat of the gas butane ($120,7 \cdot 10^6$ J/$m^3$).

This heat equation should give a temperature function $u$ for the combustion of butane, but it yields extremely high temperatures, which look unrealistic.

Do I miss a constant before the source term in the equation or is my physical analysis off?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the constant you have next to $U_{xx}$? Specifically, what are its units?

Comment: That's the thermal conductivity in $Wm^{-1}K^{-1}$

Comment: In that case, the units don't match up. If $U$ is a temperature, on the LHS we have $W \neq J $, you're missing a factor of time somewhere. As for physical analysis, I think it would be easier if you explained what you see the picture as? What is the domain of the solution? Is the source a point source?

Comment: Thanks for replying! It should be a steady state ($u_t=0$) model on domain [0.1] with a 'combustion of butane - source' between 0.3 and 0.7 (so that's where we also will have 2 heaviside functions: $\cdot H(x-0.3)-H(x-0.7))$. Boundaries are the two walls with temperatures of 300K and 600K.

Comment: Looking at [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) constants: on purely dimensional grounds, I think you need to multiply your combustion heat term by $k/(c_p \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is a linear density.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense now! To conclude, what would such linear density mean physically in this case? Like in terms of the butane gas we're combusting, the air in the oven?

Comment: I think it should be the linear density of the medium through which the heat is conducted. Basically, the medium for which you used $c_p$ and $k$

Comment: Okay thank you for all the help! That medium will be air. Is there a nice way to convert the density of air to a linear density? I never worked with linear densities before